# PHP - uploading images and $_files variable

Tags: javascript, php, file

I'm creating a blog with a WYSIWYG editor for blog posts as well as an image upload for each blog post.

So my inputs look something like this, I'm including a file here called `wysiwyg.php` but this isn't really necessary for this question. (It basically has buttons for bold italics etc, and it's just included like this because I use it in other areas of my site)

```
<form action="blog_create.php" method="POST">
    <input id="title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title">
    <input id="post_image" name="post_image" type="file">
    <textarea id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
    <textarea id="meta" name="meta" placeholder="Meta"></textarea>

    <div id="wysiwyg_controls"><?php include_once("wysiwyg.php"); ?></div>
    <iframe name="richTextField" id="wysiwyg" class="news_article"></iframe>

    <input type="hidden" id="text_content" name="text_content" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="save_as_type" name="save_as_type" value="">

    <button id="blog_draft_submit" name="blog_draft_submit" onclick="return false">Save as Draft</button>
    <button id="blog_publish_submit" name="blog_publish_submit" onclick="return false">Publish</button>
</form>
```

I then use JavaScript/jQuery to submit the form like so to actually get the content of the iframe:

```
$("#blog_draft_submit").on("click", function(){
    $text_content = richTextField.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
    $("#text_content").attr("value", $text_content);
    $("#save_as_type").attr("value", "draft");
    this.form.submit();
});
$("#blog_publish_submit").on("click", function(){
    $text_content = richTextField.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
    $("#text_content").attr("value", $text_content);
    $("#save_as_type").attr("value", "publish");
    this.form.submit();
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working properly for the file input or being able to access anything that should be in the Global `$_FILES` variable.

If I do `var_dump($_FILES);` I get:

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

But when I do `var_dump($_POST);` I get:

```
array (size=8)
  'title' => string '' (length=0)
  'post_image' => string 'image.png' (length=23)
  'description' => string '' (length=0)
  'meta' => string '' (length=0)
  'wysiwyg_image' => string '' (length=0)
  'text_content' => string '' (length=0)
  'save_as_type' => string 'draft' (length=5)
```

Is this because of the way I am submitting via JS or am I actually doing something wrong? Will I need to create a seperate parsing file and do an `XMLHttpRequest` and something AJAX-like?

### Edit

AJAX is not needed.

Comment: Do a google search on AJAX file uploads.  It's NOT as simple as you'd think: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23980733/870729

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX file upload PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php)

Comment: try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `<form>` tag

Comment: @marcogomes Thanks a million that was exactly what I was looking for much simpler than trying to send it all via ajax. Put it down as an answer and I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `<form>` tag

Some rules to follow when we use are working with `$_FILE`:

> 1. Check if the `file_uploads = On` on the php.ini file
> 2. Make sure that the form uses method="post"
> 3. The form also needs the following attribute: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`(*It specifies which content-type to
>      use when submitting the form*)

Without the requirements above, the file upload will not work.